# LabelledTypeClass does not work for ADT with case object

Tags: scala, shapeless

Given the [shapeless type class derivation example (with `Show`)](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/shows.scala).

How to adapt it to work when there is a case object :

```
case object Snafu extends Super
```

Currently it fails to compile with exception during macro expansion:

```
scala.ScalaReflectionException: <none> is not a term
    at scala.reflect.api.Symbols$SymbolApi$class.asTerm(Symbols.scala:199)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$SymbolContextApiImpl.asTerm(Symbols.scala:79)
    at shapeless.GenericMacros$Helper$class.mkTransCase(generic.scala:394)
    at shapeless.GenericMacros$$anon$2.mkTransCase(generic.scala:122)
    at shapeless.GenericMacros$Helper$class.mkToReprCase(generic.scala:411)
    at shapeless.GenericMacros$$anon$2.mkToReprCase(generic.scala:122)
    at shapeless.GenericMacros$Helper$$anonfun$19.apply(generic.scala:573)
    at shapeless.GenericMacros$Helper$$anonfun$19.apply(generic.scala:573)
    at scala.Function2$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function2.scala:54)
    at scala.Function2$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function2.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:272)
    at shapeless.GenericMacros$Helper$class.mkCases(generic.scala:338)
    at shapeless.GenericMacros$$anon$2.mkCases(generic.scala:122)
    at shapeless.GenericMacros$Helper$class.deriveInstance(generic.scala:573)
    at shapeless.GenericMacros$$anon$2.deriveInstance(generic.scala:122)
    at shapeless.GenericMacros$.deriveInstanceAux(generic.scala:131)
    at shapeless.GenericMacros$.deriveLabelledInstance(generic.scala:117)
    implicit val showInstance = Show[Super]
                                    ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got answer from Miles on Twitter:
https://twitter.com/milessabin/status/541954842076659712

It's going to be fixed soon.